# Wikipedia Page for the Poisson Kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

On the Wikipedia page for the Poisson kernel, it gives the following formula:
$$u(re^{i\theta})=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}f(e^{i\theta})d\theta$$
where $u$ is holomorphic on the open unit disc, $f$ is $L^1$ on the boundary of the unit disc, and $u$ corresponds with $f$ almost everywhere on the boundary of the disc. Does this mean that, given a general measure $\mu,$ and $f\in L^1(\partial B_1(0),\mu),$ then $u$ corresponds with $f$ $\mu$ almost everywhere with the following formula
$$u(re^{i\theta})=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}f(e^{i\theta})d\mu(\theta)$$
or do we lose claims about u and f when we do this? If so, is there a list of conditions $\mu$ must satisfy so that nothing changes?

Comment: $d\theta$ is integration w.r.t. Lebesgue measure and 'almost eveyrwher' is w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, I suppose what I mean is: Can you integrate wrt $d\mu(\theta)$ without affecting the theorem? I fixed the post to correspond with this.

Comment: I don't think I understand the quesion. It is obvious that if $\mu$ is  a degenerate measure then only very specific harmonic functions have the form you want.